# Caching Google Maps to the Server

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm newish to web development and am doing something with the Google Maps API. I'd like to minimize the number of requests that are made to Google for licensing reasons, as well as the obvious performance cost. I was thinking an option might be to cache the map on the server-side and then make requests against the cache from the client. This isn't an attempt to circumvent the licensing agreement, it just doesn't make much sense to me to reload the map entirely when refreshing the page. Is this a viable approach or is there an alternative?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this page
http://www.google.com/permissions/geoguidelines.html.
that says: "You may not scrape or otherwise export Content from Google Maps or Earth or save it for offline use." So if you cache tiles, that will be a violation of the Terms of Service.